# How do I change the background color of a row in a GridView if a checkbox in the row is enabled?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I would like to change the background color of all the rows with value for "active" column unchecked in a GridView. I tried the following way but it doesn't work:

```
 protected void GdvDetails_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox chkItem = null;
    foreach (GridViewRow grRow in GdvDetails.Rows)
    {
        if (grRow.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            chkItem = (CheckBox)grRow.Cells[6].FindControl("active");

            if (chkItem.Checked )
            {
                grRow.BackColor = Color.Red;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

The error message is "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: What line (and of which code example) is that exception coming from?

Comment: and from "GdvDetails.SelectedRow.BackColor = Color.LightGray;" if sec part is executed.

Comment: When the GridView is bound, are you creating the checkbox programmatically? That is, is the checkbox defined in c# code or in aspx markup?

Comment: in aspx markup.....what i want to do is check this particular checkbox column which is populated from the search query and then assign the color if its unchecked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this WORKS :)

```
 protected void GdvDetails_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox chkItem = null;
        foreach (GridViewRow grRow in GdvDetails.Rows)
        {
            if (grRow.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                chkItem = (CheckBox)grRow.Cells[6].FindControl("CkbActive");
                bool bl = chkItem.Checked;
                if (bl == false)
                {
                  grRow.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And the aspx file has

```
 <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID= "CkbActive" Checked ='<%# Bind ("active") %>' Enabled="false" runat="server"/>
                </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
```

in the GridView GdvDetails.

i didn't use the code under onrowdatabound because its an event for each row and i thought it will iterate unnecessarily. And this works... just in case anyone else is fumbling like me?!! thx for all the help

Answer (score 2):

Your code doesn't work because you need to do it on `RowDataBund`

```
protected void CustomersGridView_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{

    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
      //Paste your code here.

    }

}
```

And add a handler for RowDataBound as so:

```
<asp:gridview id="CustomersGridView" 

        allowpaging="true"
        onrowdatabound="CustomersGridView_RowDataBound" 
        runat="server">
      </asp:gridview>
```

Comment: i tried doing it in rowdatabound and also rowcreated but it throws the same error message !!

Comment: This is probably the way you want to go. Even if you go with looping through the results in a different event, I think checking the RowType is your problem. Either way, the answer is here.

Comment: i tried this code now it throws no error but the rows which are unchecked are not changed                   protected void GdvDetails_DataBinding(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox chkItem = null; 
         foreach (GridViewRow grRow in GdvDetails.Rows)
        {
           if (grRow.RowType== DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            
               chkItem= (CheckBox)grRow.FindControl("active");

            if (chkItem.Checked)
            {
               
                grRow.BackColor = Color.Red;
            }
        }
    }

Comment: @debutante: No, you didn't try my code. Again, you need to do it on **OnRowDataBound** not on **DataBinding**.

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle `RowDataBound` event instead of `DataBound` event, so put you in `RowDataBound` event as below:

In aspx page, after added the event the code will look like:

```
<asp:gridview id="GdvDetails" 
    onrowdatabound="GdvDetails_RowDataBound" 
    runat="server">
 </asp:gridview>
```

In code behind(.cs):

```
protected void GdvDetails_RowDataBoundd(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{   
  if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
  { 
     CheckBox chkItem = (CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("active");
     if (chkItem.Checked)
     {
         GdvDetails.SelectedRow.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: i tried it in rowdatabound and added the handler but still it throws the same error

Comment: Are you sure the `Id` of the `CheckBox` inside the `GridView` is `active`, if not please correct it or put correct id at here `(CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("active");`(remove `active` and put correct Id of the checkbox)

Comment: i tried to change the <asp:checkboxfield> to <itemtemplate> and gave the checkbox an id as CkbActive and now the code line is               chkItem = (CheckBox)grRow.Cells[6].FindControl("CkbActive");        i introduced breakpoints and i get the value of the ckeckbox as false ot true in a boolean variable. but the gridview does not change it backcolor as it should.